# Cyrillic symbols are not displaying correctly on embedded device

Tags: c++, linux, qt, character-encoding, embedded

For embedded device I have some problems with displaying of the **Cyrillic** symbols. As result I need to use crutch code to display my text correctly:

```
QString getErrorStr()
{
    #ifdef STB_VERSION
            return error_str.toLocal8Bit();
    #else
            return error_str; // PC version
    #endif
}
```

where error_str has type **QString**. Moreover for some embedded devices all are ok without strange conversion return error_str.**toLocal8Bit**(). Could you explain how works it when toLocal8Bit is used - for me the conversion too - but it works.
P.S. I use 32 bits GNU/Linux

Comment: The embedded devices that need `toLocal8Bit` don't support UTF-8; however they do support code-paged based character sets.  `toLocal8Bit` converts to the local code-page encoding, if it can be determined, else it converts to the `Latin1` encoding.

Comment: Hi Richard. Really I'm not sure that I have understood your answer. It seems I have two types of embedded devices : where this problem exists and where not... Does it depend from qt version? Configuration rootfs? Is there best way to resolve this issue without any defines?